# Extract first N position of floating number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of floating point value, and I'd like to plot it onto a graph. How can we extract the first 4 precision from a floating number, before putting into another new list?

```
C = []
C.append(23.1234567890)
C.append(14.1234567890)

print ('C - ' + str(C))

D = []
D.append(C[0])
D.append(C[1])

print ('D - ' + str(D))
```

Got

```
C - [23.123456789, 14.123456789]
D - [23.123456789, 14.123456789]
```

Expecting

```
C - [23.123456789, 14.123456789]
D - [23.1235, 14.1235]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a string representation pretty easily:

```
>>> '{:.4f}'.format(23.1234567890)
'23.1235'
```

You can also use the `round` function:

```
>>> round(23.1234567890, 4)
23.1235
```

Note that if you use `round`, the number will almost never be *exactly* to the 4 digits of precision that you want due to the representation of floating point numbers.

Comment: For any user arriving at this question using python 3: please note that using an f-string is standard in python 3. Per pylint's (consider-using-f-string)[https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/consider-using-f-string.html] documentation, an f-string is better than a .format string. For the code example provided above, this can be done with `f'{23.1234567890:.4f}'`. `print(f'{23.1234567890:.4f}')` will get you `23.1235`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, for example, through string manipulation:

```
strC = split(str(C), ".")
strC = strC[0] + "." + strC[1][:5]
print ('C - ' + strC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using string formatting:

```
C = []
C.append(23.1234567890)
C.append(14.1234567890)

print ('C - ' + str(C))

D = []
D.append(float("%.4f" % C[0]))
D.append(float("%.4f" % C[1]))

print ('D - ' + str(D))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mathematically remove the unneeded digits, using the modulo `%` function:

```
C = []
C.append(23.1234567890)
C.append(14.1234567890)

print ('C - ' + str(C))

D = []
for i in C:
    D.append(i - (i% (10**-4)))

print ('D - ' + str(D))
```

Where `-4` is the number of digits you want to keep. `10**-4` is `0.0001`.